# What does $\mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{\infty\}$ mean?

Tags: notation

A random variable $X$ takes values in $\mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{\infty\}$? Does it just mean $X$ takes values $0<X<\infty$?

The part Im confused with is $\mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{\infty\}$. What does  $\mathbb{N}_0 \cup \{\infty\}$ actually mean?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It probably means $\{0,1,2,3,\cdots,\infty\}$. (That is, $X$ can take values of $0$ or $\infty$ too.)